# what is the algorithm for function that check how many series in ascending order array have. and detect the longest series in c

Tags: c, arrays

i have problem with this assignment :

write an array of 100  positive number until negative number appear ;
then check how many series in ascending order the array have then write the first longest series in the array it means if i have 2 series in ascending order have 4 numbers i will write the first 4 number appear

for example :
the array:
 12,    3 ,   4 ,   23,    5 ,   46,    5,     6 ,    7,     78  ,   67 ,   68  ,  134 ,   45 ,    46 ,   47  ,   67  ,    11   ,   23   ,   18  ,    -3
Number of series: 4

Longest series: 5  6  7

my work ;

```
   #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
   #include <stdio.h>
   #define size 100



    void Series()
      {
int arr[size],i=0,count=0,num,NumberOfSeries=0,seriesLong=0;
printf("Enter to 100 positive integers   negative to stop  \n");
do{
    scanf("%d",&num);
    arr[i]=num;
    i++;
    count++;
}while (num>0);

printf("the array is:\n");
for(i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    printf("%d ",arr[i]);
}


for(i=0;i<count-1;i++)
{
    while(arr[i]==arr[i+1]-1)
    {
          i have no idea what to do here
        }


}

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int arr[] = {12,3,4,23,5,46,5,6,7,78,67,68,134,45,46,47,67,11,23,18,-3};
    int count = 21;
    int i;
    int pos=0, len=0;

    for(i=0;i<count-1;++i){//i<count-1-len
        int k;
        for(k=0;arr[i+k]<arr[i+k+1];++k)
            ;
        if(k>len){
            len = k;
            pos = i;
        }
        i += k;
    }
    printf("Longest series: ");
    for(i=pos;i<=pos+len;++i)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```